# ArrayList string - Retrieve Values using Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Parsing the value from JSON and stored it into a variable using Groovy. below is the value stored in that variable.

```
[[UserName:usernameX, Password:passwordX]]
```

The format is Arraylist, how can I retrieve the UserName and Password value like [`usernameX`and `passwordX`].

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, double [[]] and no quotes. I don't know how your data gets into an ArrayList, but if you can get the data in a Groovy Map, you can do it like this:

```
Map a = ['UserName':'usernameX', 'Password':'passwordX']

a.each { k, v ->
    println v
}
```

prints:

```
usernameX
passwordX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the nested array-list straight into a map:

```
Map map = [[UserName:'usernameX', Password:'passwordX']].collectEntries{ [ it.UserName, it.Password ] }

assert map == [usernameX:'passwordX']
```